# Why is my stage input processor working on the desktop but not on an Android device?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

In my project, I have a button in my stage with a listener.

The problem is that the listener method changed is fired when running the game in desktop but it is not fired when running the game on an Android device.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are touch input dispatched as mouse input in Libgdx?

Comment: i realized that there is a difference between the rendering position and the actual position of the actor, any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514152/libgdx-coordinate-system-differences-between-rendering-and-touch-input